# Connection between android and PHP

Tags: java, php, android

This is my code:

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", "12345"));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("message", msg));
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://localhost/select.php");
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

When I started the application program should open select.php file, but nothing happends.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You should have a read of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask - as it is not clear what your question is.

Comment: -1 ... this question was asked many times. first `localhost` is emulator/device not host of emulator ... second on ICS(or even HCB) app throwing error when you're doing http operation on UI thread ...

Comment: about localhost http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/devices/emulator.html#networkaddresses ... about exception http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is load up your PHP script from your Android device.

You need to change http://localhost/select.php to the IP address of the machine hosting the script (e.g. http://192.168.1.12/select.php)

You need to ensure that you are connected to the same network as your android device when testing this.

When you deploy the application you will need to change the address to the live address of that script, e.g. http://some.domain.com/select.php

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
HttpParams httpParams=new BasicHttpParams();
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParams);
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", "12345"));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("message", msg));
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/select.php");
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

Answer (score -1):

make sure you can visit the url in your browser(mobile's or emulator's). if  the localhost is your pc,change it to 10.0.0.2.

Comment: When I visit the url in my browser the php script works.I changed "localhost" to "10.0.0.2" but when I started the application, wait 2-3 minutes and shows "Activity Login(in application Login) is not responding" . In browser "http://10.0.0.2" doesn't work, too.

Comment: -1 should be 10.0.2.2 not 10.0.0.2 ... for references see my comment under a question